# KCL for this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis

I have this circuit and I know that for \$V_1\$ (taking current exiting the node as positive) it is \$\frac{-(8-V_1)}{2} +\frac{V_1}{4}-\frac{V_2-V_1}{1} -4=0\$ but for \$V_2\$ I'm slightly confused. To find \$I_d\$ is it just \$V_2\$? 
Also since terminals A and B are not connected, what's the voltage at A? Is it 8 or 0?

[image]

Comment: Please use the schematic editor to include the schematic in your question.

Comment: Solve \$\ \\ \frac{V_1}{1\: \Omega}+\frac{V_1}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_1}{4\: \Omega} = 4\: \textrm{A}+\frac{V_2}{1\: \Omega}+\frac{8\: \textrm{V}}{2\: \Omega}+\frac{0\:\textrm{V}}{4\: \Omega}\\ \frac{V_2}{1\: \Omega}+\frac{V_2}{1\: \Omega}+4\: \textrm{A}=\frac{V_1}{1\: \Omega}+\frac{0\: \textrm{V}}{1\: \Omega}\$ for \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node V2 is handled the same as node V1: The sum of the currents into the node is zero.  The current in your schematic labeled \$I_d\$ is 4A, due to the independent current source.  So the equation for node V2 is:
$$
\frac{V_1-V_2}{1\Omega} - \frac{V_2}{1\Omega} - 4A = 0
$$
Using this equation and your equation for node V1, you can solve for voltages \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$.  The voltage at A is \$V_2\$; it is neither 0 nor 8V.